# Express.js is the session and cookie used by the static file middleware?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

With the following express.js application:

```
app.use( cookieParser );
app.use( session( /*options*/) );
app.use( serveStatic( './dir' ) );

app.get( '/foo', onlyLogicThatNeedsSession )
```

I presume that the session data is being acquired even when static files are being served.

**1**: is this correct?

If so, that would imply that the app would be better structure as:

```
app.use( serveStatic( './dir' ) );

app.get( 'foo', cookieParser, session, onlyLogicThatNeedsSession )
```

**2**: would the give a performance advantage? I.e. if the session store was redis, the redis server would not be getting hit when serving static files?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the middleware are executed in order, so ideally you would put the static middleware at the very top so that you can bypass any unnecessary additional request processing.

Comment: Would that not mean the file system would be hit for every request?

Comment: Yes, because there's no way to know if the request is for a file or not. I guess you could write your own static serving middleware that uses watchers to monitor the directory for file/directory changes and keep those file lists cached (to avoid `fs.stat`ing for every request). However that could get very unwieldy...

Comment: For sure. Just wondering if there is a better way of grouping middleware? A way of adding one piece of middleware which contains many middlewares. I know express apps can be nested, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: i.e. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920839/express-js-is-the-session-and-cookie-used-by-the-static-file-middleware/24921812?noredirect=1#comment38749595_24921812

Comment: I'm not sure how grouping middleware would help solve the problem.

Comment: @Ross if you are calling `app.use('/static', express.static(` then the file system is only hit for routes starting with 'static'